# Duplicate 'Content' items were included. .json file in assets folder in .net core angular 6 web app

Tags: angular, visual-studio, .net-core

I have a .Net Core 2.1 web application using Angular 6 for the front-end, developed in Visual Studio 2017.

Inside my Angular assets folder I also have a json folder with a single file: iconClasses.json. When I publish this, I first build the angular app with `ng build --prod` from within the ClientApp folder. This moves the .json file to the dist folder, as expected:

[image: ClientApp src and dist folders showing assets/json folders]

In my .csproj the only ItemGroups are:

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="ClientApp\dist\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="appsettings.Development.json" />
        <!--<Content Remove="ClientApp\dist\assets\json\iconClasses.json" />-->
    </ItemGroup>
```

Publishing this results in the following error:

> Duplicate 'Content' items were included. The .NET SDK includes
>   'Content' items from your project directory by default. You can either
>   remove these items from your project file, or set the
>   'EnableDefaultContentItems' property to 'false' if you want to
>   explicitly include them in your project file. For more information,
>   see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were: 'ClientApp\dist\assets\json\iconClasses.json'

Uncommenting the line that explicitly removes this file allows the publish to proceed, but the file is removed from the final published package.

Comparing the .js files in the dist/assets/js folder to the .json in the dist/assets/json shows that they are all of build action 'Content' and 'Do not copy'. Setting the build action of the .json file to 'None' simply adds the `&lt;Content Remove />` as above, but also:

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="ClientApp\dist\assets\json\iconClasses.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Again, this simply results in the .json file being removed from the publish package.

I did notice that the src\assets\json\iconClasses.json file's build action was set to 'Content' whereas the other src\assets files were set to 'None', so I set the .json file to 'None' also. However, this resulted in the same error, unless the dist version was explicitly removed also.

Adding the following to my PropertyGroup in my .csproj includes the .json file in the dist/assets/json but then misses out other files my system needs:

```xml
<EnableDefaultContentItems>false</EnableDefaultContentItems>
```

So, how can I have a .json file in the assets folder get moved to the dist assets folder? Is the only way to set `EnableDefaultContentItems` to false, figure out all the missing files and add them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Change the adding of the dist folder from this:

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="ClientApp\dist\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

to this:

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="ClientApp\dist\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

i.e. change it from `Content` to `None`.

---

**Extras:**

Only the .json files in the e2e and src folders needed to be explicitly removed, not the whole folders themselves:

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="appsettings.Development.json" />
        <Content Remove="ClientApp\e2e\tsconfig.e2e.json" />
        <Content Remove="ClientApp\src\tsconfig.app.json" />
        <Content Remove="ClientApp\src\tsconfig.spec.json" />
        <Content Remove="ClientApp\src\tslint.json" />
        <Content Remove="ClientApp\src\assets\json\iconClasses.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

This is because any .json (and .config) files are automatically included. `wwwroot` is also automatically added, but is not used in this angular client app.

And since I'm using `ng build --prod`, I went ahead and told VS to stop trying to compile the typescript, so added this in the `PropertyGroup`:

```xml
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```html
    <ItemGroup>
         <Content Include="ClientApp\dist\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
    </ItemGroup>
```

> The .NET SDK includes 'Content' items from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file...

By default, .NET Core SDK includes this folder already (along with everything else in ClientApp/)
What you should try instead is removing the src folder (and everything else you don't want to publish, e2e etc.) from the published location, like so:

```html
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="ClientApp\src\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: If I remove the `<Content Include="ClientApp\dist\**\*"` section then the iconClasses.json file is the *only* file that is copied over on publish. And even if I don't have the `<None Include="ClientApp\src\**" />` section then the src folder is not included anyway. Only some setup files (such as angular.json, package.json etc) seem to be included by default.